# Heapifying an array

Tags: c++

I'm currently coding a small heapify code that repeated runs bubble down but everytime it seems like nothing's happening. Not sure what's wrong here maybe I'm missing something?

```
template <class T>
void PriorityQueue<T>::heapify (int* arrs, int size){
    int i = (size-1)/2;
    while (i >= 0){
        bubbleDown(arrs, i, (size));
        i--;

    }
}

template <class T>
void PriorityQueue<T>::bubbleDown (int* arrs, int i, int size)
{
    //Each level node's are indexed at 2^(level) - 2 to 2^(level+2) - 2
    //Children of these node's levels are indexed at 2i+1 and 2i+2
    //The parent of node i, is indexed at (i-1)/2

    int leftChildren = (2*i)+1;
    int rightChildren = (2*i)+2;
    int largest = i;
    if (rightChildren < size)
    {
        if (arrs[leftChildren] < arrs[rightChildren]){
            largest = rightChildren;
        }
        else{
            largest = leftChildren;
        }
        if (arrs[i] > arrs[largest]){
            largest = i;    
        }
    }
    else if (leftChildren < size)
    {
        if (arrs[i] < arrs[leftChildren]){
            largest = leftChildren;
        }
    }
    if (arrs[i] < arrs[largest])
    {
        int temp = arrs[i];
        arrs[i] = arr[largest];
        arrs[largest] = temp;
    }

}
```

I'm calling it like this:

```
PriorityQueue<int> test;
    int arr[] = {89, 29, 36, 48, 94, 13, 27, 70, 76, 37, 42, 58};
    test.heapify(arr, 12);
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++){
        cout << arr[i] << endl;
    }
```

Console prints out it the same way the array has been initialized.

UPDATED:
Still getting weird results
[89, -842150451, 36, 29, 94, 0, 27, 70, 48, 37, 42, 13]

The results I should be getting is
[94, 76, 89, 70, 48, 58, 13, 27, 36, 29, 37, 42, 23]

Comment: Is `arr[largest]` a typo, or does your `PriorityQueue` also have a member named `arr` that's distinct from `arrs`?

Comment: Also... what does the template argument `<T>` actually change within `PriorityQueue`?  Seems like it should be `T* arrs` and `T temp`, etc. within the `PriorityQueue<T>` implementation.  (Not that that's causing your immediate issue.)

Comment: Oh that was for testing purposes, regardless this should work for integers and @JoeZ yes I fixed that typo, and it turns out the result is a little bit weird I'll edit my post

Comment: You still have a typo left while swapping.

Comment: man.. that was the problem

Comment: @user2472706 : Why does your class have an internal array named `arr` (or do you have a global array named `arr`?) but does all of its work on array passed in named `arrs` instead?  I think that goofiness is the root cause of this bug.

Answer (score 0):

Basic typo error. Should really use more meaningful names

Comment: Delete the question rather than adding such an answer.